# Migrate existing iOS app form objective c to Swift

Tags: swift

Is there any advantage of migrating an existing iOS application from objective c to Swift? I already have some apps which are written in Objective C. I know from developer point of view it could be faster and easier to maintain but from users point of view, does it make the app faster, low memory consumption or any other advantage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a highly opinionated question, but here are some of the reasons I can think of:

- It can be faster in some operations than Objective-C. The users will not notice a very big difference though.
- For future proofing, just in case Apple drops Objective-C in the next 5 to 10 years.
- For future proofing, since a lot of new frameworks and libraries will be written for Swift

When creating new projects, there are definitely a lot more benefits to using Swift. For existing projects, maybe not so much. Either way, you can also migrate to Swift file by file. You don't have to convert the whole project at once.

Comment: Have you found any solutions to migrate code from Obj C to Swift? Some frameworks, converters etc...? Thanks in advance